# Newton's first law - elevator lift upward and downward force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

[image]

Why does $F_c$ is equal to $F_g$ and why $F_c$ isn't greater than $F_g$? $F_c$ is moving it upward right, so the force must be greater than gravity to pull it upwards I think.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton's_first_law

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! Could you please explain what is unclear to you in the solution given? Thanks!

Comment: The key phrase is “constant velocity” - the lift is *not* accelerating.

Comment: Possible duplicate or at least related: [To lift an object, do we need a force equal to its weight, or greater than its weight?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/510399/to-lift-an-object-do-we-need-a-force-equal-to-its-weight-or-greater-than-its-w/510401#510401)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To lift an object, do we need a force equal to its weight, or greater than its weight?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/510399/to-lift-an-object-do-we-need-a-force-equal-to-its-weight-or-greater-than-its-w)

Comment: I believe there is the answer from the related post:
" in order to actually lift the object, you do need to provide an upward force which is at least slightly greater than the weight of the object. Once you apply such a force even for a tiny amount of time, the object would pick up an upward velocity because it would have been subjected to an upward acceleration for that tiny amount of time. Once this is accomplished, you can reduce the magnitude of the upward force to be exactly the same as the magnitude of weight and the object will continue to move."

Answer (score 1):

Initially, the elevator is at rest and supended, so Fg = Fc. Then, in order to move upward, it has to accelerate thus, Fc > Fg. When the elevator gets a suitable speed, then moves with constat velocity (acceleration vanishes), by the second law of newton: Fc-Fg = ma = 0, so Fc = Fg.